In AWS Lex (v2), how do I reference a subSlot to use it in dialogue or conditions?
Take an example of a composite slot type fullName with firstName and lastName using the correct built-in slot types. I can collect this information easily, but how do I use it? If I want to say "thanks, John" instead of "thanks, John Doe," how do I do so?
Another example is based on the following: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/latest/dg/composite-slots.html
If I have collected that a car is a 2021 White Toyota Camry, can I run a conditional on the year so older cars are given different outcomes than newer cars? Can I say "We'll take great care of your Camry" by referencing the subSlot?
I've tried referencing them by using $ and navigating down the tree, {slot.subSlot}, {subSlot} from within the composite slot itself... nothing works, and there's nothing in the documentation for what seems like a very common, simple use case.
